# Xcode custom template with folder

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode-template

I created template with folder but why is my folder blue ?
How can I fix blue folder. How Can I create gray folder ?

My custom template folder.
[image]

My custom template info.plist

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you can't. I couldn't haha. I just need to cut that blue folder to somewhere else like Desktop and then I usually add them again to the project :(